# MS Access - Grouping fields for better control in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am creating a very light CRM tool using MS Access (MS Access basically the only option because I have been asked to do it without cost beyond labor and no server or infrastructure support beyond space on a networked drive).

I am currently working on a Task Assignment form where a manager could assign specific customer contact tasks to a customer service rep (CSR).  I have a form.  On that form are nine rows - one for every CSR - and 9 columns - one for every task.  The manager assigns a task by filling in a check box and then clicking save.  This data then gets saved to a table for Task Assignments.  Right now the labels and initial values for the CSR names and current assignments are pulled programmatically by DLookups - one for each control object (90 lines).  The assignments are then written to the table by a "Do While Not r.EOF/r.MoveNext (where r is an records set from the table) loop (another 90 lines).

My issue is this created a lot of crap code that I am not happy with.  This isn't easily extensible and looks like shit.  What I want is to be able to group each row of data fields (The CSR's name as a text box and their 9 assignments as check controls) as a group so I can iterate over that group programmatically.

What I want is to group each set of 10 fields together and then be able to do something like:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(cancel As Integer)
    Dim db As DAO,Database
    Dim r as DAO.Recordset
    Dim CSR as TaskGrouping 'Where TaskGrouping is the new group name thing I have created
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set r = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_TaskAssignments")
    r.MoveFirst
    For Each  CSR in CSRGrouping
        CSR.CSRName = r.Fields("CSRName")
        CSR.Task1 = r.Fields("Task1")
        CSR.Task9 = r.Fields("Task9")
        r.MoveNext  'I am ignoring the case where I need to ensure that r.EOF is not reached.  
    Next CSR
End Sub
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a Continuous Form?  That is, assuming your table is set up with a CSRName field and the 9 Task fields.  This way, it would automatically adjust if more (or less) CSRs were on the team.  What you did is going to cause you to have to go back and edit the form to adjust for that manually.

Comment: Could you create a private collection or dictionary with all the appropriate mappings which is initialized in a separate method? Then you can basically iterate through like you are suggesting so the logic looks clean. You still have the ugly initialization but it's isolated from your logic.

Comment: "one for each control object (90 lines).", why not 9x9 = 81 lines or 9 lines? can you explain pleasse?

Answer (score 0):

What about to think about 2 tables, tblManagers (key IDManager, autonumbering)and tblTasks (key IDTask, autonumbering)?

The tables can be easily updated added or removing items. There is no relations between the 2 tables (as I understood).

A third table is tblSelectedTasks that could be the source for your selection form. In this table you push the selection choose by each manager.
This table has two foreign keys, Manager_ID and Task_ID, related with the key in the above table and a key IDSelectedTask (Autonumber).

When you login as a manager you define the key value of Manager_ID to write in the new record of the selected task. 
a Combo-box can show you the tasks that you can select. It picks values form tblTasks and it's bounded to Task_ID. 
This table can have a Status with which you can filter your tasks and their completion status.

The loop to scan selected tasks, managers or tasks will be very short cause it will be in the form

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
dim strSQL as string

strSQL = "Select ... FROM ... WHERE ..."
Set rs = Currentdb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

do while not rs.EOF

  <your code here>

  rs.movenext
loop

rs.close
set rs = nothing
```

Let me know.